# Jquery detect input focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a conversion web app to teach myself Javascript. The user can input data with a number pad (basically a calculator without the operators). I also set up a function to detect keystrokes (1-9) which insert data just like the number pad. And also character 'c' which clears all data

My problem is that I also have a search field (which uses auto complete to enable the user to search for other conversions). I dont' want the user to search for something using the 'c' or number keys, and have it enter data into both the number pad, and search field.

My idea was to create a if statement to determine if the search field was active (focused), and if it was to change a variable (enabled) to false, thus disabling the keystroke detection.

The problem I am having is that the function holding the if statement with the focus attribute is not working.

If my rambling made no sense hopefully the code will clear things up.

*Here is the if statement with the focus attribute*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(':focus').attr('#searchInput') == 'input')){
        enabled === false;
    }
});
```

*Here is the code for key stroke detections (I omitted the redundant parts to save space*

```
document.onkeydown = function(event){
    var key = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
    if(enabled === true){
        if(key === 67){
            clearInput(input); //Clears form input (input is my form ID)
        }else if(key === 48){
            writeInput(input, zero); //Zero is a var equaling 0
        }
        ...
    }else{
        return false; //if enabled is false don't detect keystrokes
    }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If anything doesn't make sense I will be happy to explain (or edit the post.)

Comment: what do you think `enabled === false;` is doing?

Comment: Enabled is a Boolean variable. My idea was to change it to false when the focus IF statement was true. Thus disabling the keystroke detection. Thanks for the quick comment.

Comment: `.attr('#searchInput')` dont get it. Where did you put it?

Comment: @ChrisFrank So perhaps you should assign variable using single `=` sign

Comment: I declared the variable outside of the function

Comment: @ChrisFrank still if you want to change variable value use single `=` sign. Use `==` and `===` to compare two variables

Comment: Good advice. Thanks.

I am still trying to figure out all the syntax rules for Javascript :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
   if($('#searchInput').is(':focus')) {
      return ; // search field is focused, ignore other part of function
   }
   var key = e.which;
   // do your code here
});
```

Comment: You are awesome! That worked perfectly. Saved me a lot of time. And cleaned up my code as well. Thanks!